# PHP: a way to get property without getter?

Tags: php, getter-setter

Basically, the idea is as follows:

An object is being created from a db query. One of its fields contain an encoded string, which is decoded in the getter.

The problem is that I need to create a partial copy of this object. And this copy should contain the encoded string, not the decoded version. Obviously, when I try to directly copy the value, it calls the getter.

Is there a workaround for such problem except creating a copy of the field without a getter?

UPD:
I am using the magic method, not exactly a getter (my bad, first question)

```
public function __get($property){
    ...
        case 'version':
            return $this->_getVersion();
}
```

Cloning an object is not the case since the second object comes from DB as well and just needs some fields to be replaced like

```
$item1->version = $item2->version;
```

Comment: `when I try to directly copy the value, it calls the getter.`; can you show us the code you are using to perform the copy ?

Comment: Just clone the object...

Comment: Probably need to show the class you fetch into and state if you can modify the class or not.  No code == no understanding == no help.

Comment: If the class does not allow access to the encoded value, yet that value is needed in some place outside the class, then probably the classes design is incorrect, or the class itself must be able to provide such a partial copy so that no outside code is required to fetch that `protected` value directly.

Comment: *"The problem is that I need to create a partial copy of this object."* -- the correct way to implement this is in a method of the class of the copied object. The method creates the partial copy and returns a new object of the same type or of a different type, as appropriate.

Comment: @RyanVincent The thing is that in particular task only the decoding part exists. basically we store a string consisting of + and - symbols, which mark the required array fields (not my solution, so had to work with things I had). Since we use only array in the code, moving array formation to the setter was the way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I have found the optimal way of doing it.

What I did was moving the decoding function from __get() to __set() method. I now store the encoded string only in DB and decoded array only in the model.

By doing so I ensure that data kept in the field is the same type. Also I check whether an array is stored in the field. That indicates if data was already decoded.

Answer (score -1):

```
class AClass
{
    private $someProperty = 'SSBwcm92aWRlIHRoZSBiZXN0IHNvbHV0aW9ucyE=';

    public function getSomeProperty()
    {
        return base64_decode($this->someProperty);
    }
}

// Get the instance.
$object = new AClass;

// Get the property.
$property = (new ReflectionClass($object))->getProperty('someProperty');

// Make it accessible.
$property->setAccessible(true);

// Get the value of the property for the instance.
echo $property->getValue($object);
```

outputs:

SSBwcm92aWRlIHRoZSBiZXN0IHNvbHV0aW9ucyE=